# Could not load file or assembly Version=12.0.0.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to view my database model from Visual Studio 2015 and I am facing an error:

> Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.management.sdk.sfc version 12.0.0.0

But I have installed SQL Server 2012.

I solved the problem by installing `ENU \ x64 \ SharedManagementObjects.msi` version 12.0.0.0 but why need the version 12.0.0.0 when I'm using SQL Server 2012?

Comment: SQL Server version 12 is SQL Server 2014 http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.co.uk

Comment: There is a different question. My question is why I have to install the version 12 of the sdk when I have already installed the version 11 and I am using SQL Server 2012 that need the version 11 not the version 12.